# Deploy Outlook Add-in on an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We are trying to host a custom Outlook Add-in on an AWS EC2 instance. We are using a windows server in EC2 to host this. Currently we are using webpack dev server to host it locally and everything is working fine. Now we need to deploy and have this app run as a service in the Windows Server.

We have tried to deploy the build on an IIS server. But we were not able to proceed after logging in to the application. We are getting the error as a Bad request. We also have tried to deploy it on Apache server using XAMP. But the results were the same. It is getting deployed in the webservers, however when we are hitting the backend application it seems to be erroring out.
The error we are getting is Error: redirect_uri_mismatch, when we try to authenticate and redirect to the authenticated home page of the application.

When we deploy the same using webpack-dev-server in the instance, It is working as indented.

We are facing issue to identify the proper reason for this error and unable to deploy the service in EC2.

EDIT
[Screenshoot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGtBj.png)
[Screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XWVl.png)

Comment: Does addin loads properly? Can you share the manifest for the addin and screen shot of the failure to help us understand the problem better.

Comment: In case of a web app run as a service you are responsible for handling HTTP requests on your own. Do you run any web server, for example, based on ExpressJS?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT  We are creating a custom outlook email Add-in which will parse email contents from the outlook inbox. When we click on this add-in, an authentication screen will appear and we need to enter our credentials for authentication. After authentication the next step is to authorize our application to grant permission to access/read emails from the Outlook inbox (refer screenhot -1 in the question).

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT When our application is deployed using the development server (Webpack-dev-server), we are prompted for authorization (working correctly as intended). 
But when we deploy the same application using webservers like IIS and Apache , after authentication we are not prompted for authorization instead we are getting Error : invalid_request 'redirect_uri_mismatch' (refer screenshot-2)

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev We used  Webpack-dev-server as development server, .To run build of the same application we used webservers like IIS and Apache

Comment: Are files accessible on the IIS server? Can you access them in the web browser?